# Python 2.7: how to find the index of the first letter of each word in a string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm looking for a way, in Python, to detect the index of the first character of each word in a string:

```
string = "DAY MONTH      YEAR    THIS   HAS RANDOM   SPACES"
```

I would like to find the position of each 'word', so this output would be:

```
[0, 4, 15, 23...]
```

Does anyone have any idea how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "DAY MONTH      YEAR    THIS   HAS RANDOM   SPACES"
>>> [match.start() for match in re.finditer(r'\b\w', string)]
[0, 4, 15, 23, 30, 34, 43]
```

Comment: Arghghg, beaten by 24 seconds ;) (I just used `\b(\w)` though...)

Comment: @JonClements: The next time, leave your message posted as well - I use to upvote equivalent answers to the "first one" for sake of fairness. I am sure there are more people thiunking like me. Besides, a couple equivaletne answers just demonstrate this is the "one obvious way to do it"